# Where I can find a complete reference of cake bake command?

Tags: cakephp, command, cakephp-1.3, acl

is there url for learning cake bake command.
for example i want learn acl in command , i write in command

> cake acl help

but this is not complete.
thanks for your help.

Comment: [StackOverflow is not a link farm or search engine](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/128549/172661). This is not the place for asking for URLs to other sites. Your question is inappropriate here.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can find the help from following resources

[CakePhp Cheat Sheet](http://cheat.errtheblog.com/s/cakephp/)

[Code Generation with Bake](http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/view/1522/Code-Generation-with-Bake)

[Console and Shell](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/console-and-shells.html)

[Baking with CakePhp](http://www.jamesfairhurst.co.uk/posts/view/baking_with_cakephp)

Comment: This is not an answer (which is why SO isn't the place for this type of question). It becomes meaningless if the outside links are unavailable for some reason, and they're not searchable for future readers here. The [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) is pretty clear about how to answer questions here.